# How can I import a module from a parent directory?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, python-import

I have the following directory structure for my Python project:

```
lib 
    __init__.py
    tasks.py
    api(directory)
        __init__.py
        app.py
```

Now, I want to import the tasks module into app.py. If I just type

```
import tasks
```

it magically works in Pycharm, but when executed via bash I get an error message saying "No module named tasks". I also tried

```
from .. import tasks
```

which gives me

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does `import tasks` work when executed in Pycharm?

Comment: How did you "execut[e] via bash"? Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912) help?

Comment: This helped me to understand some of my problems, thank you. I am still really confused why it works when executed with pycharm, and I still can't get behind the whole package thing. I would have thought I could execute it as a module using `python -m lib.api.app` from the lib directory, but that just gives me "No module named lib"